# How to fix: Servlet web service endpoint '' failure. ? ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, web.xml, redeploy

What should I do ?

- I got the server up (Payara/glassfish).
- I used /asadmin to create jms and jdbc resources for applicaton and          I got connection-pool up.
- I'm using payara-full-6.2023.4.

**Here is my successful install:**

```
`INFO[m] Installing /home/NWTiS_1/spetrovic/spetrovic_zadaca_3/pom.xml to /opt/m2/org/foi/nwtis/spetrovic/spetrovic_zadaca_3/1.0.0/spetrovic_zadaca_3-1.0.0.pom
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1mReactor Summary:[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] spetrovic_zadaca_3_lib_1 1.0.3 ..................... [1;32mSUCCESS[m [  2.618 s]
[[1;34mINFO[m] spetrovic_zadaca_3_lib_2 1.0.4 ..................... [1;32mSUCCESS[m [  0.838 s]
[[1;34mINFO[m] spetrovic_zadaca_3_wa_1 1.0.0 ...................... [1;32mSUCCESS[m [  4.975 s]
[[1;34mINFO[m] spetrovic_zadaca_3_wa_2 1.0.0 ...................... [1;32mSUCCESS[m [  2.171 s]
[[1;34mINFO[m] spetrovic_zadaca_3 1.0.0 ........................... [1;32mSUCCESS[m [  0.010 s]
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1;32mBUILD SUCCESS[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------`
```

**When i try do redeploy my application "spetrovic_zadaca_3_wa_1" here is the problem:**

```
[[1;34mINFO[m] [DeployerRedeployMojo] Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-payara:jar:1.9.10 for container payara
[[1;34mINFO[m] [talledLocalContainer] Parsed GlassFish version = [6.2023.4]
[[1;34mINFO[m] [talledLocalContainer] Command deploy failed.
[[1;34mINFO[m] [talledLocalContainer] remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet web service endpoint '' failure. Please see server.log for more details.
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Total time:  7.685 s
[[1;34mINFO[m] Finished at: 2023-05-16T14:45:11+02:00
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal [32morg.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven3-plugin:1.9.10:redeploy[m [1m(default-cli)[m on project [36mspetrovic_zadaca_3_wa_1[m: [1;31mExecution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven3-plugin:1.9.10:redeploy failed: GlassFish admin command with args (--interactive=false --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile /opt/payara-full-6.2023.4/glassfish/domains/password.properties deploy --force --contextroot spetrovic_zadaca_3_wa_1 /home/NWTiS_1/spetrovic/spetrovic_zadaca_3/spetrovic_zadaca_3_wa_1/target/spetrovic_zadaca_3_wa_1-1.0.0.war) failed: asadmin exited 1[m -> [1m[Help 1][m
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[[1;31mERROR[m] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Server log that I got here is this:

```
[2023-05-16T16:17:05.961+0200] [Payara 6.2023.4] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=88 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1684246625961] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet web service endpoint '' failure
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:361)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:630)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:617)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:552)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:574)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1879)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1755)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:409)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:236)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:367)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:179)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
]]

[2023-05-16T16:17:05.962+0200] [Payara 6.2023.4] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=88 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1684246625962] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app]]

[2023-05-16T16:17:05.972+0200] [Payara 6.2023.4] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=243 _ThreadName=Thread-30] [timeMillis: 1684246625972] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception in thread "Thread-30" ]]

[2023-05-16T16:17:05.973+0200] [Payara 6.2023.4] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=243 _ThreadName=Thread-30] [timeMillis: 1684246625973] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  jakarta.ejb.EJBException: Attempt to invoke when container is in Undeployed
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2109)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2104)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
    at jdk.proxy101/jdk.proxy101.$Proxy413.saljiPoruku(Unknown Source)
    at org.foi.nwtis.spetrovic.zadaca_3.zrna.__EJB31_Generated__JmsPosiljatelj__Intf____Bean__.saljiPoruku(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:410)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
    at org.foi.nwtis.spetrovic.zadaca_3.zrna.JmsPosiljatelj$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.saljiPoruku(Unknown Source)
    at org.foi.nwtis.spetrovic.zadaca_3.dretve.SakupljacLetovaAviona.run(SakupljacLetovaAviona.java:31)
]]

[2023-05-16T16:17:05.974+0200] [Payara 6.2023.4] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00192] [jakarta.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=88 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1684246625974] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Undeployment failed for context /spetrovic_zadaca_3_wa_1]]

[2023-05-16T16:17:05.989+0200] [Payara 6.2023.4] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=88 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1684246625989] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet web service endpoint '' failure]]

[2023-05-16T16:17:05.989+0200] [Payara 6.2023.4] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.org.glassfish.jdbc.deployer] [tid: _ThreadID=249 _ThreadName=Executor-Service-28] [timeMillis: 1684246625989] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "resource" is null]]
```